# Drupal Views argument - Provide default argument: PHP code

Tags: php, drupal, view

I would like to pass an argument of 'home' to the View (which is a block) as the default argument when the current page is the front page. The 'else if' portion of the code works fine. Thanks.

This code goes in the "PHP Argument Code" text field when you select "provide default argument" in Views.

```
$path = explode('/', drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']));
if ($is_front) {
  return 'home';
} else if (arg(0) = 'node' && arg(1) != 'add' && arg(2) != 'edit' && arg(2) != 'delete' && $path[0] != '') {
  return $path[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$is_front = $_GET['q'] == '<front>' || $_GET['q'] == variable_get('site_frontpage', '<front>');
```